# Explain the below lines of put(key,value) method of concurrentHashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I was reading a implementation of inserting a key value pair in  [ConcurrentHashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.put%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29) here.

I am unable to understand the below lines.

```
 int j = (hash >>> segmentShift) & segmentMask;
        if ((s = (Segment<K,V>)UNSAFE.getObject          // nonvolatile; recheck
             (segments, (j << SSHIFT) + SBASE)) == null) //  in ensureSegment
            s = ensureSegment(j);
        return s.put(key, hash, value, false);
```

Somebody please explain.

Comment: Are you asking what the `<<` operator is?

Comment: I once read that people that wrote `java.util.concurrent.*` are among the brightest people of this world. I have also read that they themselves don't quite grasp how the `concurrent` package works in some cases as well as it does.

Does that sorta answer it?

Comment: I know << operator. But if you can explain me in words what they are trying to do in 2nd or 3rd line.

Answer (score 1):

The method call:

```
UNSAFE.getObject(segments, (j << SSHIFT) + SBASE)
```

is equivalent to a normal array access `segments[j]`, but is likely faster because it requires no bounds checks. `SBASE` is the offset to where the array data begins in the `segments` array. `SSHIFT` is log<sub>2</sub> of the array index scale, so `j << SSHIFT` calculates the raw byte offset of index `j` in the array.